# The integral closure is normal

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $A$ be an integral domain. Denote by $A'$ the integral closure of $A$ in $\mathsf{Frac} \:A$. Is it true that $A'$ is normal?

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less a tautology: the integral closure of $A$ in its fraction field is integrally closed (easy exercise), and integrally closed rings are normal (read the section on localization of Atiyah--Macdonald).